# Android: how to have two separate layouts

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

there are lots of layout questions when I search here, but I just can't find something to address this - and its possibly because I am going about it the wrong way, or perhaps using the wrong terms to describe what I am trying to achieve.  I apologise in advance if this is answered elsewhere, but would appreciate some pointers.

What I want to do is have a screen for a login task, then once logged in I go to another screen to do some other stuff (and this screen will have a totally different layout).

The question I have is: Can I have two separate layouts (ie: main.xml and login.xml), and depending where I am in the code, just change them?  And if so, how?

I did try adding `setContentView(R.layout.login);` in the code, but it just seems to pick the last one set and stick with it regardless of where in the code you are.  I also tried breaking the login part into another class then use `startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));` to call it, but its almost like it ran in parallel to the main app, since things in the main app kept going even before the login was completed.

ie: in the main activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
Toast.makeText(this, "This is main", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Then I get the login screen pop up, with the toast message popping up over it - and the main activity just carries on regardless of what I do in the login activity.  The login activity does not just end either - do I need to kill it, or do a System.exit() on it?

I'm hoping its something simple I am doing wrong, I'm kind of trying to kludge ideas from various websites and the two textbooks I have, but nothing seems to be working.

Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you override `onStop` your activity can record that it is no longer visible to the user and not make inappropriate toast. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop

Comment: I'll give this a go.  Something like just having a 'stopped' boolean that I set true in the OnStop() method, then do a while(stopped){} after I start the login activity?  Cheers, Steve

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to set it as false in `onStart()`

Comment: It didn't work... caused the GUI to lock up, but I now get what you mean by back-button hell.  I've restructured the program to start with the login screen then open the new one once authed, and in the background the login screen kills itself once the socket is connected.  Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to have two activities `MainActivity` and `LoginActivity` that each have their own layout. You will get into back-button hell if you don't take that approach.

(Re. "things in the main app kept going even before the login was completed" you'll need to add more detail to explain what you were seeing, that doesn't sound right to me.)

Comment: Thanks Jim... this is what I have right now, and I have that StartActivity above to call the login activity from the main one - but the next line in my main app is a Toast, which shows up straight away instead of waiting for the login to complete, which is why I am getting confused.  Also, the login activity does not return to the main activity when its complete, which I can't quite figure out.  Steve

Comment: @Steve - add a bit more code to the initial post (such as the 2 activities, in particular the onCreates()) and we can hopefully help a little more. :) Jims suggestion is correct, you may want to review http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html again for the lifecycles - just because you change to another activity does not necessarily mean the old activity is completely gone.

Comment: Thanks Klaus, I added the pertinent code in my question with a slightly better description... I'm still struggling with what to do here tho - I expected the login activity to cause the main one to 'freeze' until the login one ended... but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is launch a new screen when a user a logged in properly. just launch a new activity when the user is properly logged in.
Take help from the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,Login.class);      
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Again in the MainActivity use **onActivityResult()** method to receive the result if you want to perform some action back in the Main Actvity.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, but the user will never get back from the login screen if they don't login properly.  Its actually just a simple authentication more than a security screen.  The main app will be useless to them without the authentication completing.  Cheers, Steve

Comment: that was just an example a gave you according to your requirement . you can implement this in different way also.

Comment: The concept is useful to me now, thanks... I didn't really understand this when I first asked the question, but I think I do now.  Cheers

Comment: I accepted another answer that was more in line with what I needed, but I do try to always accept an answer when I ask questions... I've marked your answer as helpful tho... Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

Maybe the better option is to use two different activities. When you start the second one (main activity), call `activity.finish()` in the first one (login activity).

Comment: Hi Pedro, sorry I am not sure what you mean here.  How do I call activity.finish()?

Comment: just after you start the second activity. This is probably after the user presses a button to authenticate. Try to do it after the line ``startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));`` (you can simply call ``finish()`` because you are already in the activity.

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks... I understand now.  Originally I was starting the main app, calling the login one, and then switching back... I've changed it to your suggestion (as with the suggestion above) and its working now.  I've used finish() to kill the login screen once the socket connects, and it seems to be working.  Cheers